# how to exclude only certain elements in json objects of array using for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I want to call the function `checkIsObjectEmptyOrNot` only if all "name", "age", "class" fields are not null. If all those (without id and book_id) values are null, the function should return false. `id` and `book_id` should be excluded from this filtering process because `id` and `book_id` always have some value from Laravel backend.

```
 checkIsObjectEmptyOrNot(object){

        for (var key in object) {
            if (key != 'id' && key != 'book_id' && key != null) {
                break;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I have a Json array like,

```
[
    {
         "id": 1,
         "book_id": 2,
         "name": "myname",
         "age": 25,
         "class":null,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "book_id": 2,
        "name": "myname2",
        "age": 25,
        "class": null,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "book_id": 2,
        "name": "myname3",
        "age": 25,
        "class": 10,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need a new function for this. `Array.filter` can do the job. See below snippet. Will return all the valid items.

```js
const arr = [
 {
 "id":1,
 "book_id":2,
 "name":"myname",
 "age":25,
 "class":null,
 },
{
 "id":2,
 "book_id":2,
 "name":"myname2",
 "age":25,
 "class":null,
 },
{
 "id":3,
 "book_id":2,
 "name":"myname3",
 "age":25,
 "class":10,
 },
].filter((item)=>{
  return item.name && item.age && item.class
})

console.log(arr);
```

But Still if you need to have a function this can be it

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "book_id": 2,
    "name": "myname",
    "age": 25,
    "class": null,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "book_id": 2,
    "name": "myname2",
    "age": 25,
    "class": null,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "book_id": 2,
    "name": "myname3",
    "age": 25,
    "class": 10,
  },
]

function checkIsObjectEmptyOrNot(object) {
     for (var key in object) {
        if (key !== 'id' && key !== 'book_id' && object[key] !== null)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(checkIsObjectEmptyOrNot(arr[0]));
console.log(checkIsObjectEmptyOrNot(arr[1]));
console.log(checkIsObjectEmptyOrNot(arr[2]));
```

This will return true if all there `name`, `age` and `class` are not `null` or `undefined` or `false` and `true` otherwise

Hope this helps :)

Comment: the problem is there are more fields except name,age and class. every object have id and book_id. but other fields can be null or have value. what i want is call the above mentioned function only when all fields are null except id and book_id. Thanks

Comment: @MadusankaBDissanayake update the second snippet.. this is what you need..

Comment: this gives me same answer as in checkIsObjectEmptyOrNot(object){
  for (var key in object) {
    if (key != 'id' && key != 'book_id' && key != null) {
      break;
      return true;
    }

  }
  return false;
}

Comment: OK Then what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Also for the array you have provided none of them have any object where all the properties are null.. So they all are valid as per your requirement.. And in you code snippet you were checking the `key!= null` which will actually check the key to be null and not its value.. While in my snippet its checks for the value to be null `object[key] !== null` hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `forEach` .

```
    var arr = [
         {
         "id":1,
         "book_id":2,
         "name":"myname",
         "age":25,
         "class":null,
         },
        {
         "id":2,
         "book_id":2,
         "name":"myname2",
         "age":25,
         "class":null,
         },
        {
         "id":3,
         "book_id":2,
         "name":"myname3",
         "age":25,
         "class":10,
         },
        ]
         var flag = 0;
         arr.forEach(function(singleObject){
            for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(singleObject)) {
                if(singleObject[key] != _id || singleObject[key] != book_id){
                    if(singleObject[key] != null){
                     flag = 1;
                    }
                }   
}
});
   //if condition satisfies if all the value is null except _id and book_id
    if(flag == 0 ){
    //call function.
    checkIsObjectEmptyOrNot()

    }
```

Comment: the problem is there are more fields except name,age and class. every object have id and book_id. but other fields can be null or have value. what i want is call the above mentioned function only when all fields are null except id and book_id. Thanks